# What does chemically happen to rubber when it soaks in mineral spirits type 1?

Tags: organic-chemistry, aromatic-compounds, rubber

Mineral spirits(mineral turpentine)type 1 is a mixture of aliphatic and alicyclic hydrocarbons with a maximum content of 25% aromatics
and less than 0.1% benzene and all kind of impurities.
I have noticed that if i soak piece of rubber(2cm^3 cube)in mineral spirits type 1,the rubber swells.I assume that a specific type of hydrocarbons diffused into the rubber and cause it to swell.
Which type of hydrocarbons are diffused into the rubber and responsible for the swelling?(the aromatic ones?)and is there a way to remove the mineral spirit(residues)from the swollen rubber or the hydrocarbons in the mineral spirits are actually bonding to the rubber molecules,so it can't be removed?

Answer (score 1):

Mostly aromatics, some alicyclic.

Probably the only way is evaporation, at temperature being trade off between patience and thermal damage.

Be aware that of the rubber object may not revert exactly to original shape or size. Some residues may remain and arrangement of macromolecules may change.

Comment: @poutnic,As you said that even after evaporation,some residues may remain.Do you mean solid residues that can not be removed?and for that reason,if the rubber was food grade or suitable for potable water,those residues,after the evaporation,make the rubber not suitable to use with food or water anymore?

Comment: I have meant solvent residues. Some molecules may be bound by van der  Waals' force stronger then others.

Comment: Okay,so does that mean that the rubber will not be suitable to use with food or water anymore(assuming that they were suitable before they were soaked in mineral spirit type 1)and there is nothing to do about that?or it depends on some factors?

Comment: I have not  commented food compatibility aspect intentionally.

Comment: Okay,i understand.The problem is that i know(by reading)that the white spirits,type 1,contains a toxic materials like benzene etc.So if they are part of the solvent residues,the rubber won't be suitable anymore to use with food or water.But i know,also that everything is related to the amount of the toxic residues and this is what i was trying to understand,if the rubber can be suitable again to the same application(after i give it long time to evaporate)or it won't be safe,no matter what.But again i understand the sensitive part of this question.Thanks.